# Error getting value from jdatechooser and adding it to database java

Tags: java

How can I show jcalender?

How to get the selected value from it and add it to database?

From google I found a file called jcalender-1.4. I've added it to the jframe but when I try to get selected value from it and add it to the database it shows error. Table is created but error shows while inserting values. The exception in insertion method is shown. I've tried to print the value the value of db9 by commenting the insertData method and it shows null. Below is the link of JCalender jar file that i've used.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/yxe86ylfm4u6be8/jcalendar-1.4.jar?dl=0

```
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New Reservation");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        db1=textField.getText();
        db2=textField_1.getText();
        db3=textField_2.getText();
        db4=textField_3.getText();
        db5=textField_4.getText();
        db6=textField_5.getText();
        db7=textField_6.getText();
        db8=(String)comboBox.getSelectedItem();
        db9=dateChooser.getDate();
        db10=textField_7.getText();
        db11=(String)comboBox_1.getSelectedItem();
        db12=(String)comboBox_2.getSelectedItem();
        db13=dateChooser_1.getDate();
        db14=dateChooser_2.getDate();
        try {
            insertData();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        public static void createTable() throws Exception{
            try{
                Connection con=getConnection();
                PreparedStatement create =con.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hotelDetails(_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,name varchar(65),"
                        + "surname varchar(65),address varchar(65),cnic varchar(65),mobileNo varchar(65),email varchar(65),city varchar(65),gender varchar(65),dob Date,country varchar(65),roomType varchar(65),"
                        + "roomNo varchar(65),checkin Date,checkout Date)");
                create.executeUpdate();
                System.out.println("Table Created");

            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Table Not Created.Try Again","Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        } public static void insertData() throws Exception{
                try{
                    Connection con=getConnection();
                    PreparedStatement posted=con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO hotelDetails(name,surname,address,cnic,mobileNo,email,city,gender,dob,country,roomType,roomNo,checkin,checkout)VALUES('"+db1+"','"+db2+"','"+db3+"','"+db4+"','"+db5+"','"+db6+"','"+db7+"','"+db8+"','"+db9+"','"+db10+"','"+db11+"','"+db12+"','"+db13+"','"+db14+"')");
                    posted.executeUpdate();
                    System.out.println("Values Inserted");

                }catch(Exception e)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Can't Insert Data","Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }

            }
```

Comment: What's the error message that you get during the insertion?

Comment: It shows can't insert data... the exception in insertData method

Comment: If you actually print the exception, it will most likely tell you it can't insert - namely, a particular field is empty, or specified in incorrect format (like Date, for example)